# Why does ScaleModifier make sprite flicker?

Tags: android, andengine

I'm playing around in AndEngine and learning this non-documented while making a splashscreen. I'm aware there's a class SplashScene, but as I'm learning I'm trying all kind of ways.

However, I can't seem to get this one right. The screen is 240x320 (W x H) and splash screen texture is 480x640 so i'm scaling it down to fit the screen. Texture loading etc is working fine, but when the sprite is shown I first see the large texture for 0.1secs, then it gets scaled down. I want it to get scaled down prior shown. Been trying everything, moved the call to attachChild() to onLoadComplete(), using setVisible(false), etc but I see the texture getting scaled down everytime.

Why?

Here's my code:

```
@Override
public Scene onLoadScene() {
  this.scene = new Scene();

  // Texture sizes
  final int sX = mSplashTextureRegion.getWidth();
  final int sY = mSplashTextureRegion.getHeight();

  // Center on camera
  final int cX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - sX) / 2;
  final int cY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - sY) / 2;

  // Scale factor according to camera
  final float scaleFactor = Math.min((float) CAMERA_WIDTH / sX, (float) CAMERA_HEIGHT / sY);

  // Init sprite
  splashScreen = new Sprite(cX, cY, mSplashTextureRegion);
  splashScreen.setVisible(false);

  // Rescale the splash-screen to fit the display, move it to (0, 0) and show it.
  splashScreen.registerEntityModifier(new ScaleModifier(0.1f, 1.0f, scaleFactor));

  //splashScreen.registerEntityModifier(new ScaleAtModifier(0.001f, 1.0f, scaleFactor, 0, 0));
  // splashScreen.registerEntityModifier(new SequenceEntityModifier(
  // new ScaleModifier(0.1f, 1.0f, scaleFactor),
  // new DelayModifier(0.2f)
  // ));

  return scene;
}

@Override
public void onLoadComplete() {
  scene.attachChild(splashScreen);
  splashScreen.setVisible(true);
}
```

If I rewrite `onLoadComplete()` in to this:

```
@Override
public void onLoadComplete() {
  scene.attachChild(splashScreen);

  mHandler.postDelayed(korv, 1000);
}

private Runnable korv = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    splashScreen.setVisible(true);

  }
};
```

the flicker is gone, but that doesn't feel like a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ScaleModifier adjust the scale over the specified time factor - in your case 0.1f

```
ScaleModifier(0.1f, 1.0f, scaleFactor)
```

What you probably want is to scale the Sprite directly using

```
SplashScreen.setScale(scaleFactor);
```

do that before attaching the child and you should be fine.